# Trying to create an account and getting error messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-handlebars

When running my [code](https://github.com/NoobyPilot/TowerDefense-JS) and trying to register, i get a series of Error messages:

```
(node:16084) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError: User validation failed: password: Path `password` is required.
    at new ValidationError (D:\JavaScript\TowerDefense\NewTowerDefense\TowerDefense-JS\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\validation.js:30:11)
    at model.Document.invalidate (D:\JavaScript\TowerDefense\NewTowerDefense\TowerDefense-JS\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2259:32)
    at p.doValidate.skipSchemaValidators (D:\JavaScript\TowerDefense\NewTowerDefense\TowerDefense-JS\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2108:17)
    at D:\JavaScript\TowerDefense\NewTowerDefense\TowerDefense-JS\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:981:9
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11) (node:16084) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1) (node:16084) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code. POST /users/authRegister -
- ms - -
```

I got no idea what it is I have done wrong and again, as I got no idea which file causes the problem I am posting the whole repo here.

### Edit

After double-checking the Mongo connection string, I now get this in addition to the recent error message:

```
(node:7964) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)

(node:7964) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:7964) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: error is not defined

    at User.findOne.then.user (D:\JavaScript\TowerDefense\NewTowerDefense\TowerDefense-JS\public\javascripts\userHandler.js:53:13)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:7964) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
```

Comment: Can you paste form parameters?

Comment: The error is self explanatory. You're trying to connect to a mongodb instance without supplying the password or it's malformed. Check your monogodb connection string